# InvalidCharacterError in svelte/sapper when resizing window

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I build a website with sapper. When I resize my window (smaller, then big again), I get this error in Firefox:

```
String contains an invalid character in svelte
```

in the file *index.mjs:249*. Clicking on the file leads to this function:

```js
function attr(node, attribute, value) {
    if (value == null)
        node.removeAttribute(attribute);
    else if (node.getAttribute(attribute) !== value)
        node.setAttribute(attribute, value);
}
```

And the error seems to be here: `node.setAttribute(attribute, value);`
Anybody an idea what could cause this error? I have some conditional logic to display components depending on the windows size:

```js
<script>
  let windowSize;
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth={windowSize} />

{#if windowSize >= 768}
  <Image />
{/if}
```

Could this cause the error?

**UPDATE**

Google Chrome throws this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '`rel' is not a valid attribute name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. There was a backtick (`) within the attributes of an `<a />` tag:

```
<a
  `rel="noreferrer"
   aria-label={external}
   class="social-media-icon"
   target="_blank"
   href={external}>
```